# Edit Crystal Reports RPC file in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have Crystal Reports 13.0.5 for VS2010.  I have some report templates in *.rpc format that I need to edit (just minor layout changes), but I can't open then in Visual Studio.  I can open *.rpt files just fine, but not the *.rpc files.

Any ideas on how to edit these without having to buy a full version of Crystal?

Also, what's the difference between *.rpc and *.rpt files?  Nearly all of my googling for "crystal reports rpc file" or "edit crystal reports rpc vs2010" returns results about Remote Procedure Call, and I know that can't be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently just renaming the file from *.rpc to *.rpt is sufficient to edit the report in Visual Sutido.